# Translating and scaling a glutSolidCube();

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw this object:

[image]

So far, I've gotten this, the first half draws the bottom section, the second half draws the top section:

```
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1, length/largeWidth, 1);
glTranslatef(0, largeWidth/2, 0);
glutSolidCube(largeWidth);
glPopMatrix();


glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1, length/smallWidth, 1);
glTranslatef(0, smallWidth/2 + length, 0);
glutSolidCube(smallWidth);
glPopMatrix();
```

But this is giving me the wrong answer, there is a very large gap between the two sections, they don't meet, as if the top section's translation in the y direction is too large, but I dont see why.

Comment: scale after translating

Comment: I swapped the order of glScalef and glTranslatef and its not working at all, it's giving me a really weird answer.

Comment: I just tried some random values and if I replace **glTranslatef(0, smallWidth/2 + length, 0);** with **glTranslatef(0, smallWidth/2 + largeWidth/2, 0);** it gives me the correct answer. I have no idea why though... That translation doesn't make sense in my head.

Comment: you may remove both smalWidth/2, it's useless. Only length is relevant

Comment: ok, sorry for my comment, I made an error, it's better to have your scalling first (when your model is on (0,0,0)), but the translation you apply is width dims, which is not what you want. You want the obj translated by the lenght dim, so just translate one of your model with lenght, and that's it

Comment: looking again, why are you scaling on y axe with width, it's non-sens, you have to scale on the x/z axis(assuming y is your up vector)

Comment: Because when you use solidCube, the centre of the cube is located at the origin, so in order to bring it up to the surface, I need to translate by its width/2 in the y direction

Comment: it would have been less tricky to have a solidCube of dimension=1

Comment: If I made the dimension 1, then the scaling would just be by length right? The translations would remain the same thought right?

Comment: if dim=1 then you have to scale (width,length,with) and translate (0,length(/2),0) which is far more clear. (Sorry for not having looked wisely directly.)

Comment: @j-p Using your idea to make the dimension 1 made everything a lot easier and I solved the problem. If you post an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: Having helped is my salary :-)